# JOOQ forcedTypes to Boolean

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Code generation worked fine. The db char(1) field1,field2 are mapped to Boolean in the code base.

```
 <forcedTypes>
                <forcedType>
                    <name>BOOLEAN</name>
                    <expressions>field1,field2
                    </expressions>
                </forcedType>
            </forcedTypes>
```

But While doing the insert to DB, i get

```
A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink CHAR 'false' to length 1. Error
```

The sql generated by JOOQ is `insert into mytable ("field1", "field2", ) values (cast(? as boolean), cast(? as boolean))`

This is trying to insert false/true in the DB but i want to insert 1 or 0. 
Need help.

I have Derby for Dev functional testing and oracle for other environments. I use the same JOOQ generated stubs(Generated using Derby DB) for both the db's. This seems to be working fine for Oracle but not for Derby.

http://blog.jooq.org/tag/boolean-data-type/ states that Oracle supports and Derby will not support this conversion. Need a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using data type rewriting in the code generator

You're currently making use of the feature ["data type rewriting"](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/) in your code generator configuration. This means that jOOQ's runtime has no idea about the actual data type in your database. It just behaves as though the data type really *IS* `BOOLEAN`. This means:

- The Oracle JDBC driver will convert your Java `boolean` bind values to `1` or `0` for `NUMBER` columns, or to `'1'` or `'0'` for string columns.
- The Derby JDBC driver won't convert this type but instead expect a real `BOOLEAN` column in the database.

If you want to proceed this way, you will have to make the Derby column type an actual `BOOLEAN`, not a `CHAR(1)`.

#### Specifying a `Converter` in the code generator

Another option would be to use a jOOQ `Converter` instead, where you translate the Java `boolean` to a Java `String` *first*, before passing the value to the database. That way, you can use the same data type in both of your databases. [This is documented here, in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/).